# 4017 Decade Counter Into Transistors Problem

Tags: transistors, counter, transistor-array

I'm attempting to use a decade counter with each output connected to the base of a set of transistors in parallel. So that the counter will count up, and will allow current to pass through one transistor, then the next, then the next and so on.

To do this I've produced a square wave with a 555 timer fed into the decade counter. The output of the 555 timer is fine, producing a nice square wave, and then the outputs of the decade counter are fine, turning on one by one counting up.

However when I plug this output into a transistor connected to an LED, the LED doesn't turn on. What am I doing incorrectly? Attached is a circuit diagram showing what I am doing.

Thanks[image]

Currently I have the circuit shown below (except with 80 strips of metal not 4), with the switches having to be manually opened and closed one at a time. The aim is to automate this setup to cycle through one switch being closed and all others open.[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you need to post a better schematic, showing every component's value and the pin names (not just pin numbers).

Comment: The first circuit on this page: http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/70InterestingCircuits/70InterestingCircuits.html  shows a better solution. You can find examples like that using Google. If you use high-efficiency LEDs and run them at about 5 mA each you do not even need the transistors, the 4017 can then drive them directly.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, thank you for the advice but I'm afraid that will not work for what I need.

Comment: @TonyM I've updated the schematic as requested, if there's still anything I could make more helpful please say :)

Comment: So, are you getting voltage on the output pins driving the transistors? *edit* sorry, I overlooked that you'd already said you have. Are the transistors wired correctly? What is the forward voltage of your LEDs? Bear in mind that modern green ones for instance have a VF of more than 3 volts...

Comment: A +3V supply to a 555? Spec sheet says +5V minimum.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks for the advice, I've tried a +9V now but the problem remains.

Comment: @IanBland Would the forward voltage be the problem? I manage to light the LEDs if I just pass the voltage straight through the LEDs without the transistor.

Comment: @Jack: "*I'm afraid that will not work for what I need.*". Tell us what you need and why. We can't guess. There's a built-in schematic editor on the site.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the question, added the overall aim to the original post.

Comment: There are no transistors in your schematic, just circles with 2 lines in them. I'm guessing they are _meant_ to be transistors, but we don't know which terminals are Collector and Emitter or what type they are (NPN/PNP). If you can't even be bothered drawing the symbols properly, why should we help you?

Comment: @Bruce Abbot Thanks for the message, the original schematic I uploaded did label which terminals were which, but I forgot to put them on on the schematic requested with the pin names added on. Thanks for the pointless hostility though, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the LED connected to the Collector of the NPN transistor and have the Emitter grounded. It would also be good to have a 470 - 560 ohm resistor in series with each base.

Answer (score 0):

For high-efficiency LEDs that are sufficiently bright with only one milliamp, you can get by with no driver transistors, providing the supply voltage is significantly larger than the forward "ON" voltage of the LED - roughly 2 volts.
But you will need **individual series resistors** on each LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvpX2x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you use nine driver transistors for the nine LEDs, each driver transistor will require *its own series resistor*. In your schematic, driver transistors  try to share a couple of 1K series resistors - not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use up to a 5V (or a bit more) supply and a [74HC4017](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4017.pdf) and avoid all the transistors and base resistors. Just a single 1K resistor as you have there. Plenty of drive capability in the HC series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8b8Xs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's possible to share R1 because two constraints are satisfied:

1. Only a single output is high at a time (guaranteed by the 4017 logic) so the current will be ideally the same for each state and not shared.
2. The 'off' LEDs are
   exposed to a maximum negative bias of Vout (high) - Vf, which is
   less than the maximum 5V rating most LEDs have.

The circuit would also function with a CD4017 and 3V supply, however the current output will be very low and the LEDs quite dim (limited by the outputs rather than R1).

---

If you **need** a lot more current, then the 1K won't cut it and you may need to add transistors. In which case you would have something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ATsw.png)</sup>

In this case Rs sets the LED current - Rs = (Vcc-Vf(led)-0.1V)/Iled

And you should pick base resistors so they provide 1/10 to 1/20 of Iled. 
so if Iled = 15mA, base current should be 0.75~1.5mA so the base resistor would be (Vout(high) - .7))/Ibase. If Vout(high) is 2.4V, then the base resistors would be around 1K-2K.